# weird cell size shift in css nav bar

Tags: css

Here's the situation.  I have written a css vertical navigation bar and the size of cells shrink once the enclosed links have been visted!  Please Help!  Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css">  

a.vertical:link  
{
display:block;  
 font-size:14px;  
 padding: 1px 1px;
 text-decoration:none;  
 color:#151B54;  
 background:#FFFFFF;  
 font-weight:bold;  
 width:200px;  
}  

a.vertical:active  
{  
 font-size:14px;  
 padding: 1px 1px;
 text-decoration:none;  
 color:#151B54;  
 background:#FFFFFF;  
 font-weight:bold;  
 width:200px;  
}  

a.vertical:visited   
{  
 font-size:14px;  
 padding: 1px 1px;
 text-decoration:none;  
 color:#F778A1;  
 background:#FFFFFF;  
 font-weight:bold;  
 width:200px;  
}  

a.vertical:hover  
{  
 font-size:14px;  
 padding: 1px 1px;
 text-decoration:none;  
 color:#FFFFFF;  
 background:#151B54;  
 font-weight:bold;  
 width:200px;  
}  

.verticalBorder  
{  
 background:#FFFFFF; 
 padding: 1px 1px; 
 border-style:solid;  
 border-color:#FFFFFF;  
 border-width:5px;  
 width:200px;  
}     

</style>

<div class="verticalBorder" align="left">  
<a href="http://www.stpaulncanton.org/LatchKey/latchkeynew.html"   
class="vertical">After School Child Care</a><br/>
```

Comment: Oh god. You have duplication all OVER the place. `display:block;font-size...width:200px`. Everything in common should be shoved under an a.vertical {} selector, not put in every single one.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: the `:link` pseudo-class styles unvisited links, and is setting `display:block`. When your links are visited, `:link` no longer applies and they revert to `display:inline`, their default, and thus you lose the ability to specify a width.

Beyond that, you should read up on the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/Style/LieBos2e/enter/) so you can write more concise, maintainable CSS. For example, taking advantage of the cascade, your CSS could wind up as:

```
<style type="text/css">  

a.vertical  
{
 display:block;  
 font-size:14px;  
 padding: 1px 1px;
 text-decoration:none;  
 color:#151B54;  
 background:#FFFFFF;  
 font-weight:bold;  
 width:200px;  
}    

a.vertical:visited   
{  
 color:#F778A1;  
}  

a.vertical:hover  
{  
 color:#FFFFFF;  
 background:#151B54;  
}  

.verticalBorder  
{  
 background:#FFFFFF; 
 padding: 1px 1px; 
 border-style:solid;  
 border-color:#FFFFFF;  
 border-width:5px;  
 width:200px;  
}     

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the HTML for this or link this page? Probably unrelated, but it doesn't seem like you're utilizing the cascade with the redeclaration of font-size, padding, text-decoration, font-weight, and width across all of the .vertical links.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into a test page and I don't see the effect you describe. Could there be other styles affecting your links? Use Firebug or IE dev tools to inspect the links to see what styles are being applied.